# Get Transaction History Given Policy ID using Blockfrost API

Tags: transaction, nft, blockfrost, python, asset

What's the best say to get the transaction history of an NFT collection given the policy id? I looked into Asset Transactions but this requires both policy ID and the asset ID. Is there something else I am missing? Or should I loop through each asset and see if there is a transaction? Seems super tedious though..

`https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/{asset}/transactions`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [Blockfrost](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D%7E1transactions/get) currently requires the concatenated policy *and* asset name to query asset transactions but you can use the [Koios API instead](https://api.koios.rest/#get-/asset_txs) with just the policyId since the asset name is optional.